# How can I subtract or add dates by some number and get value in epoch milliseconds?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a library which can easily achieve subtracting or adding months, day or time from a date object? I am using angularjs and looking for a solution for the following

1. some date - 3 months or 2 weeks back from the same `some` date.
2. some date + 3 months or 2 weeks forward from the same `some` date.

I tried below [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FDate) but date subtraction does not work.

```
var from = Date.now() - 60;
var previous = new Date(2014, 10, 20);  
console.log(from+", "+previous+", "+from.getDate() + "/" + from.getMonth() + "/"+from.getFullYear());
```

error in chrome console

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Comment: http://www.datejs.com/ ?

Comment: For certain operations it's easy enough to do with pure JS. It seems as though you should change `myDate` to `from` as `myDate` seems to be your undeclared (and therefore undefined) variable.

Comment: Also you should change `var from = Date.now() - 60;` to `var from = new Date(Date.now() - 60);`. I also think `Date.now()` might be deprecated if I remember correctly. The correct alternative to that method is `new Date().getTime()`.

Comment: Another thing to note is that `Date.now()` returns the amount of milliseconds (1/1000th of a second) since January 1 1970. Subtracting 60 from this value will make a very negligible difference.

Comment: @YoannAugen: I tried to use [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/2007/11/27/getting-started-with-datejs/) but is there a way to get 2 months back from a particular date? eg: `var simNow = Date.parse('11.10.2014'); var simFromNow = (30).days().after(simNow);`

Comment: @YoannAugen: [Resolved issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/datejs/4607IkCNvhk), site has old url for the library. but how can I go 30 days or few months back from a given date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest `momentjs` module. It has wide variety of choices for parsing, manipulating, display dates in javascript.

Here is the link: http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted